# Cucumber-Spring/Java not adding bean to cucumber-glue scope

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I am trying to integrate spring's DI into a simple cucumber-java-skeleton project.

I am using:
the 1.2 release of cucumber-java/spring/junit &
the 3.2.8.RELEASE of Spring

I want to use the spring annotation's that I read about in the "Cucumber for Java Book" - specifically the two tags:

```
 @Component
 @Scope("cucumber-glue")
```

from what I understood is that using these annotations are supposed to replace the manual bean creation

here is the portion of my "cucumber.xml" that is relevant (not the headers):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="hooks"/>
<context:annotation-config/>
```

I understood it as spring it will look in the package name "hooks" for any of these annotations.

here is my hooks class - which simply prints in a @Before and @After

```
package hooks;

//assorted imports

@Component
@Scope("cucumber-glue")
public class TestHooks {


@Before
public void beforeCallingScenario() {
System.out.println("***********BEFORE **** About to start the scenario.");
}

@After
public void afterRunningScenario(Scenario scenario) {
System.out.println("*********** AFTER ****Just finished running scenario: "
+ scenario.getStatus());
}
```

when I run the tests I believe it is actually finding the class because I see this printed to my console:

```
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@411e6b7e: defining beans [testHooks...
```

but when I run the tests they do not get ran.. however if i define this package in the @CucumberOptions annotation; they get picked up.

I also believe they are being instantiated because if I try to do both: that is use the glue option with the same package name in @CucumberOptions and in the cucumber.xml file - I get the following exception

```
Causedby:org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException:No qualifying bean of type [hooks.testHooks] is defined: expected single  matching bean but found 2: testHooks,hooks.TestHooks
```

My suspicion is that the "cucumber-glue" scope is not being applied

What am I missing (configuration or otherwise) for this to work properly?

Comment: In version 1.1.3 the class GlueCodeScope and GlueCodeContext where marked as default access rather than public. This makes it unavailable. I am still looking for a solution myself. Furthermore, if you want to go back to version 1.1.2, your cucumber options wont work as they were not implemented yet.